# Save time to the database also followed by date

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

i wanted to save only the "TIME" into the database.

But, what i am getting is "TIME" followed by "DATE"

Here is the screenshot of my database in the program after i added it to the database file:

[image]

If you see in the "Times" column, the time followed by the date. Where i don't want to be that (i wanted only the time shown in the "Times" column).

Moreover, i already setting the format of "Times" in the database file into "Medium Time", which is will give me "4:56PM".

Here is the screenshot of the time in the database:

[image]

The time in the database file were correct, because it shown only the time. But, while in the program where i show the database using datagridview, it shown the time followed by the date.

How do i change it so i could see the time only?

Here is the code:

```
    private void AddDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO [Record] ([Times]) VALUES (@Times)";

            conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                    _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Times", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBTimeStamp);
                    _cmd.Parameters["@Times"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

                    int _numberOfRows = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                    _sound.Play();

                    DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                    if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        ViewDatabase(sender, e);

                        ClearTextBoxes(sender, e);
                    }
                }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Basically, how do i use the "Format" in the database file into the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.ToString(formatString) method to format datetime as you want.
then you can show the resulting string in the datagrid or whatever you want.

```
var dtTime =(DateTime) dataReader["Times"];
var strTime = datTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: assuming that you are reading rows from database using dataReader

Comment: do i need to put that after after the sign `=` in the `["Times"].Value` sir? And, what i am supposed to do with `datTime`? isn't should be like this: `var dtTime =(DateTime) dataReader["Times"];
var strTime = dtTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");` instead of what you wrote.

Comment: the code I wrote is just for displaying stored time, just formatting for display. I thought you have a problem with displaying in correct format

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER 2008+ has a [TIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) datatype, you can use it for storing time, and you can take a look at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) for using it in .Net application, just a hint, you can use TimeSpan data type in .Net

Comment: Thanks. But i am using ACCESS now, not SQL.

Comment: so the best solution is to store time as number of seconds(or milliseconds) from midnight (like 3735 means 01:02:15 )and then use ad timespan data type in .Net

Comment: could you give me an example of doing that @VahiD? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store your time as count of seconds from midnight, for example in your case:

you define your Times filed in database as int, and

```
_cmd.Parameters.Add("@Times", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
_cmd.Parameters["@Times"].Value = (int)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
```

and after reading from database, you can convert count of seconds to time

```
int soconds = reader["Times"];
string time = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",seconds/3600,seconds/60,seconds%60);
```

time is your desired format to display in textbox or grid etc.

Comment: There is no DateTime.TimeOfDay sir.

Comment: sorry DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay